# How for loop can select only exact variables

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop

My for loop is running for vp1 all queues are selected and same with vpn2 and vpn3 but i need vp1 should select queue1 and  respectively vpn2 with queue2 &vpn3 with queue3 how can i achieve it

```
source ./config.csv
vpn="$vpn1 $vpn2 $vpn3"
queue="$queue1 $queue2 $queue3"
for i in $vpn 
do
    for j in $queue
    do
echo "Fetching LVQ details from $i VPN ..."
msgs=$(curl -s -X GET -u ${User}:${PASSWORD} http://${IP}:${Port}/SEMP/v2/monitor/msgVpns/$i/queues/$j/msgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is using none existant variables to create an array. You can try this

```
source ./config.csv
vpn=(vpn1 vpn2 vpn3)
queue=(queue1 queue2 queue3)
n=0

for net in ${vpn[@]}; do
    echo "Fetching LVQ details from $net VPN ..."
    msgs=$(curl -s -X GET -u "${User}":"${PASSWORD}" http://"${IP}":"${Port}"/SEMP/v2/monitor/msgVpns/"$net"/queues/"${queue[$n]}"/msgs)
    ((n++))
done
```